# Using wp_parse_args to set up Plugin Default Settings

Tags: plugin-development, options, wp-parse-args

So I want to have defaults set up for each of my plugins settings, and I'm using wp_parse_args to do so which I believe is the correct way, but I'm hitting a roadblock.

Here's my code at the moment:

```
function eddslider_options_each( $edd_slider_options ) {

$edd_slider_options = get_option( 'eddslider_options' );

/**
 * Define the array of defaults
 */ 
$defaults = array(
    'slider_insert'     => 0,
    'slider_arrows'     => 0,
    'slider_bullets'    => 0,
    'slider_effect'     => 'fade',
    'slider_theme'      => 'default'
);
/**
 *  Parse incomming $args into an array and merge it with $defaults
 */ 
$edd_slider_options = wp_parse_args( $edd_slider_options, $defaults );

/**
 * OPTIONAL: Declare each item in $args as its own variable i.e. $type, $before.
 */ 
extract( $edd_slider_options, EXTR_SKIP );

}
```

Now if I add something like:

```
$output = $slider_insert;
return $output;
```

I'm able to use `<?php echo eddslider_options_each('slider_insert'); ?>` and it will have the defined default set and work well. **How do I do this for every option though?** Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function eddslider_options_each( $key ) {

    $edd_slider_options = get_option( 'eddslider_options' );

     /* Define the array of defaults */ 
    $defaults = array(
        'slider_insert'     => 0,
        'slider_arrows'     => 0,
        'slider_bullets'    => 0,
        'slider_effect'     => 'fade',
        'slider_theme'      => 'default'
    );

    $edd_slider_options = wp_parse_args( $edd_slider_options, $defaults );

    if( isset($edd_slider_options[$key]) )
         return $edd_slider_options[$key];

    return false;
}
```